# javascript to render form rails 4.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use JavaScript to render a form. I want to click a link that will add a `New Link` form below. The `New Link` form is contained in my `links/new.html.erb` file.

Below is my "Show" page where I have a link to render a "New Link" form.

```
<h3>Links</h3>
<div id="links">
  <%= render @opportunity.links %>
</div>
<%= link_to "Add URL", new_opportunity_link_path(@opportunity, :format => :js), :remote =>     true, :id => 'new_link_link' %>
```

Below is my views/links/new.js.erb file

```
    $("<%= escape_javascript render(file: 'links/new.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('#links');
    $('#new_link').hide().slideDown();
    $('#new_link_link').hide();
```

For some reason, when I click the link I made, a new form does not appear. This code is copied and modified from `Beginning Rails 4 by Gamble, Carneiro, and Al Barazi`.

Comment: Can you alert from new.js.erb file just to make sure that control is passing over to it?

Comment: I added alert("hi!") to my new.js.erb file and nothing happened when I clicked "add url" @user2675613

Comment: can you post your controller method